# Sum of $k^4$ from $0$ to $n$

Tags: summation

How can I find this summation? I started by expanding $(k+1)^5$  and setting the summation of both equal to each other. There is some cancellation but I don't know what to do afterwards.

Comment: do u know fourier series ?

Comment: No, I haven't learned any Fourier Series yet.

Comment: @Thomas Yes but I want to know how it is derived

Comment: You can see Faulhaber's Formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula (but this is overkill).

Comment: @Batman batman always goes for overkill. no kill like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$(k+1)^5-k^5=\binom51k^4+\binom52k^3+\binom53k^2+\binom54k+1$$

Set $k=1,2\cdots,n$ and add to find $$(n+1)^5-1=5S_4+10S_3+10S_2+5S_1+S_0$$

where $S_m=\sum_{r=1}^nr^m$

More generally, $$(k+1)^{n+1}-k^{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n+1}rS_r$$

Comment: The summation of both sides, in equation, would also be to true right? Then I would just need to solve for $S_4$? How would I do that?

Comment: @Jesus $S_3$ is the sum of cubes. $S_2$ is the sum of squares. $S_1$ is the sum of natural numbers. You already know those formulas, right?

Comment: Yes, so I would just need to substract all of the terms to leave $5S_4$, then divide by 5?

Comment: @Jesus, as Sabyasachi has suggested, we need to know the sums of all the lower powers

Answer (score 0):

One way that should be easy to remember is just linear algebra. it is guaranteed that the answer is  $$ a_5 n^5 + a_4 n^4 +  a_3 n^3 + a_2 n^2 +  a_1 n + a_0,    $$ where all six $a_j$ are rational numbers. They might all be positive, I'm not sure, but $a_5 > 0.$

So, the sum up to $n=1$ is $1,$ or
$$ a_5 + a_4 + a_3 + a_2 + a_1 + a_0 = 1.   $$

The sum up to $n=2$ is $17,$ or
$$ 32 a_5 + 16 a_4 + 8 a_3 + 4 a_2 + 2 a_1 + a_0 = 17.   $$

The sum up to $n=3$ is $98,$ or
$$ 243 a_5 + 81 a_4 + 27 a_3 + 9 a_2 + 3 a_1 + a_0 = 98.   $$

The sum up to $n=4$ is $354,$ or
$$ 1024 a_5 + 256 a_4 + 64 a_3 + 16 a_2 + 4 a_1 + a_0 = 354.   $$

The sum up to $n=5$ is $979,$ or
$$ 3125 a_5 + 625 a_4 + 125 a_3 + 25 a_2 + 5 a_1 + a_0 = 979.   $$

The sum up to $n=6$ is $2275,$ or
$$ 7776 a_5 + 1296 a_4 + 216 a_3 + 36 a_2 + 6 a_1 + a_0 = 2275.   $$

So, there you go, six linear equations in six unknowns. You just solve the system with Gauss-Jordan elimination. I saw one of your questions was on row echelon form, so you know how to do this.

There are also many clever ways to do this. Matter of taste.

Comment: Don't you think that $a_0$ is obvious ? If I am correct, one less equation. In fact, I wonder how easily could we prove that for the sum of $k^i$,$a_{i+1}=1/(i+1)$ and $a_i=1/2$. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, yes, $a_{i+1} = 1 / (i+1)$ follows from methods of finite differences. Not sure about the next one. i agree that $a_0 = 0$ because the sum of $0$ terms is $0,$ but decided to leave that out as needing explanation. I imagine a good deal can be shown just by induction on the exponent.